# Java Array List Error?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
// ArrayList
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Integer obj1 = new Integer (97);
        String obj2 = "Lama";
        CD obj3 = new CD("BlahBlah", "Justin Bieber", 25.0, 13);

        ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();

        objects.add(obj1);
        objects.add(obj2);
        objects.add(obj3);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an array list with these three objects, why am I receiving this error?

```
ArrayList.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.Integer)
location: class ArrayList
objects.add(obj1);
       ^
ArrayList.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(java.lang.String)
location: class ArrayList
objects.add(obj2);
       ^
ArrayList.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(CD)
location: class ArrayList
objects.add(obj3);
       ^
3 errors
```

Comment: Anything with `Justin Bieber` in it will fail.

Comment: You cannot used reserved keywords of `Java` as your class name or variable name.

Comment: Also, it usually is not necessary to `import package.*;`  If you had not, maybe you would noticed the error by yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Because, your class name is `ArrayList`. Change your class name like,

```
 public class ArrayListTest{
     .....
 }
```

Or, use fully qualified class name `java.util.ArrayList`

```
public class ArrayList{


public static void main (String [] args)
{
  ....
  java.util.ArrayList objects = new java.util.ArrayList();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your class name `ArrayList` is already defined in `java`

see below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your class name is same as one of the Java API, you would need to use complete namesapce(with pacakge name) when you want to operate on Java API

`java.util.ArrayList objects`

Ideally, user defined classes should not named as `Java System/API class names`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read some articles about name conventions in Java. Because what you are doing now is misleading. http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Your class name is not eligible and misunderstanding. You need to use more specific names and avoid using restricted names like collections.

Comment: why are you repeating the answers?

Comment: I am not repeating, I  am suggesting to read some sources. I do not replay any answer to his question to solve the problem as everyone do. It is just misleading to create class with name like this. So it seems that he does not know name conventions

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to add the object because of line :

```
ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
```

Always use generic type when using multiple objects like `Integer`, `String`......

Replace your ArrayList declaration with :

```
  ArrayList <Object> objects = new ArrayList <Object> ();
```

Object can take Integer and String (because both are subclass of Object class)

one more point here : you can use `ArrayList` as class name then you must declare your `java.util.ArrayList` with qualified package name.....if using other then `List` like `Set`, `Map` then your can use `ArrayList` as a class name without any package declaration with `Set` or `Map`..... ideally we should not use any reserve word as a class name....

Thanks : KP

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer to add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).